# How do i reach indexPath in a custom func?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I am trying to open a second UIAlertController upon choosing an option in the first UIAlertController but I am unable to reach indexPath in order to set a property from a textField of a second AlertController. Here's the snippet:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    
    let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Choose an action", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rename a person", style: .default, handler: alert2))
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive) {
        [weak self] _ in
        self?.people.remove(at: indexPath.item)
        self?.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
    ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))
    present(ac, animated: true)
}
func alert2(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    let ac2 = UIAlertController(title: "Type in a name", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(ac2, animated: true)
    guard let newName = ac2.textFields?[0].text else { return }
    let person = people[indexPath.item]
    person.name = newName
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    ac2.addTextField()
}
```

I also get the "Cannot find 'indexPath' in scope" error in this string:
let person = people[indexPath.item]
Could you please help me to work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the indexPath into the `alert2` function. Try this new `alert2` function:

```
func alert2(alert: UIAlertAction!, indexPath:IndexPath) {
    let ac2 = UIAlertController(title: "Type in a name", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
    ac2.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil))
    self.present(ac2, animated: true)
    guard let newName = ac2.textFields?[0].text else { return }
    let person = people[indexPath.item]
    person.name = newName
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
    ac2.addTextField()
}
```

And you would replace this line:

```
ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Rename a person", style: .default, handler: alert2))
```

with this:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Rename a person", style: .default) { action in
    alert2(alert: action, indexPath: indexPath)
}
ac.addAction(action)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot find 'indexPath' in scope is given because your function is not able to find index number. you should pass Indexpath parameter through your function alert2
change your function `func alert2(alert: UIAlertAction!)` to `func alert2(alert: UIAlertAction!, indexPath:IndexPath)` then you will found the index.
for your reference :

```
func alert2(alert: UIAlertAction!, indexPath:IndexPath) {
    ... your code ...

    let person = people[indexPath.item]

    ... your code ...
}
```